# Create Enum according to range C#

Tags: c#

I have to create enum according to following age groups.
Babies ages 0–7
A child from ages 7 to 9
A preteen ages 10–12
A teenager ages 13–19
A young adult ages 20–25
An adult ages 26–65
A retiree ages 66–80
An old person ages 80+

```
public enum AgeGroup
        {
            retireeAges >  65 && <= 80,

        }
```

Comment: That's not how enums work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Bear in mind that `int i = (int)AgeGroup.retireeAges;` is meant to be legal. What would `i` be set to here?

Comment: Make it a setting: retiree ages can (will) change over time

Comment: @Stefan if retire age will ever go above 80...I'd consider bugs, crashes, and high maintenance costs in legacy software a form of protest and civil disobedience :O LOL

Answer (score 2):

An enumeration is a constant value, not a range then you can't directly express this concept. You have two options (sorted by complexity):

Store the upper limit:

```
public enum AgeGroup {
    Baby = 7,
    Child = 9,
    Preteen = 12,
    Teenager = 19,
    YoungAdult = 25,
    Adult = 65,
    Retiree = 80,
    Old = Int32.MaxValue
}
```

Obviously it makes the code to use it more complex. Why don't you use a `struct` instead?

```
public struct AgeGroup {
    public static readonly Baby = new AgeGroup(0, 7);
    public static readonly Child = new AgeGroup(7, 9);

    public AgeGroup(int fromInclusive, toExclusive) {
        this._fromInclusive = fromInclusive;
        this._toExclusive = toExclusive;
    }

    private int _fromInclusive, _toExclusive;
}
```

Of course on the top of this you MUST add:

- Proper validation for inputs.
- Comparison operators (at very least `==` and `!=` and obviously override `Equals()` and implement `IEquatable<AgeGroup>`).
- Some utility functions like `public bool Includes(int age) => _fromInclusive <= age && _toExclusive > age;`

As Jon noted you should consider to use a `class` instead of a `struct` if you're concerned about `new AgeGroup()` which will initialize both limits to 0 (well, you should). I'm using a `struct` here just to avoid the overhead of a `class` for a small 8 bytes entity (which might be less because `_fromInclusive` and `_toExclusive` might be `byte`) and to avoid null-checks when these values are used (I'd love to see this as a small read-only entity which mimics a primitive type).

Comment: It's not clear that a struct is useful here, compared with a class. In particular, `new AgeGroup()` *must* be valid, but isn't a useful value. I'd probably make it a class and make the constructor private unless there's a need to create separate instances elsewhere in code.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree about `new AgeGroup()` (while it might be useful as _empty_ or _exclude all_ or _not yet born_ it's pretty corner-case). I used a struct mostly to avoid object overhead for a small 8 bytes structure (which BTW might be less because age could be just `byte`).

Comment: Given that it's very likely that there'd be very few of these in existence, I doubt that that's an important concern in most cases. It just doesn't "feel" like something you'd normally use as a struct to me. I think it's generally a good idea to default to writing classes unless a type really feels like it's a natural struct.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand your concerns, I tend to use `struct` for tiny read-only entities (especially when I want to mimic a primitive type) and to avoid null-checks and assertions here and there but it's more a _gut feeling_ than anything else. BTW (off-topic): these days you're not active here as you used to be :( :( :(

Comment: When you want to mimic a primitive type, that makes perfect sense. That's what value types *should* feel like. This doesn't, to me. Of course, the official design guidelines are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct. The fact that we'd expect a few values of this type, and for them to be long-lived, make it feel class-like to me.

Comment: I see, following official guidelines it's not a _single value_ then it shouldn't be but also `ArraySegment<T>` is not (even if, in that case, I guess the choice has been driven by performance which aren't an issue here). I see this as something similar to `System.Drawing.Color` or `System.Windows.Media.Color`, my habit but see your point

Answer (score 0):

[Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) is constant value. It's impossible to set range or multiply values as enum.

Maybe, you need some range struct with from and to values.